Wire size for 64 VDC starter
I volunteer for a organization that is restoring a tugboat. The starter motor cables for the main diesel engine need replaced as the insulation is no longer in good condition.
The old cable had soldered lugs being stamped for 550 MCM.
It is a 64 VDC starter rated at 725 Amps. Two cable runs of 25ft each in open air from battery switch and starter contactor. Engine room is heated. I was looking at 636 DLO cable for a replacement. I understand ampacity ratings, but the 64 VDC is what I don't know about for the correct cable size. I don't want to undersize the cable.
Thanks,
Todd

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As well as the most important factor (wire cross section area and - should go without saying- made of copper), consider chemical resistance and mechanical properties of the wire insulation, stranding (since it will be subjected to vibration and flexing) and voltage rating. If it's a bit fatter on the copper and not too much different in stranding you're probably okay with DLO.

From what I can find (quick google search) 636DLO is a little heavier than 550MCM so you should be good.  64V operation means that voltage drop in the cable is probably less important than in a 24V circuit but more of a concern than it would be in a 230V circuit (where losing a couple of volts in the cables doesn’t matter that much).  You’ll want to confirm that the cable’s insulation is rated for 64V, although it’s hard to imagine that it wouldn’t be.
